# Git difftool in Windows to see list of all changed files in addition to file diffs (a la Kaleidoscope)?

Tags: git, diff, kaleidoscope

When I do a `git difftool`, [Kaleidoscope](https://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/) shows me all the files that have changed in the left sidebar:

[image]
<sub>(source: [kaleidoscopeapp.com](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/static/img/screenshots/Changeset_Blocks.png))</sub>

Is there any diff-tool in Windows that would show me such a list of files?

(I don't want the tool to open all the files at the same time in separate windows. I'm looking for a single window that will show me the list of files changed, and I should be able to click on a particular file to see its diff, as shown in the Kaleidoscope screenshot)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use git difftool in a way which lists all the files (git1.8+ recommended):

```
git difftool --dir-diff
```

> Copy the modified files to a temporary location and perform a directory diff on them.
> This mode never prompts before launching the diff tool.

You can then [integrate it with a BeyondCompare for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13637243/6309).

Or with WinMerge:

```
[diff]
    tool = winmerge
[difftool "winmerge"]
    path = C:/Program Files (x86)/WinMerge/winmergeu.exe
    cmd = \"C:/Program Files (x86)/WinMerge/winmergeu.exe\" -r -u \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

All that with:

```
    $ git difftool [<commit> [<commit>]]
```

---

The only problem is the git diff-tool, on Windows, is described [in this blog post](http://tech.nitoyon.com/en/blog/2013/07/09/symlink-dir-diff-on-windows/), by [nitoyon](http://tech.nitoyon.com/en/about/).

> On Unix and MacOS, `git difftool --dir-diff` create a symbolic link to the working directory if a right-hand file has the same SHA1 as the file in the working directory. It's very useful when we modify right-hand files with a difftool.
>
> On Windows, instead of creating symbolic links, `git difftool --dir-diff` copy back right-hand files to working directory after `difftool` program exits. I want to use symlinks on Git for Windows like Unix and MacOS.

Note: **On Windows, administrator privileges is required to create symbolic links**.

> Run GitBash as an administrator, and enter following command.

```
$ git difftool -d --symlinks [<commit> [<commit>]]
```

> If you want, create an alias on `.gitconfig`.

```
[alias]
    d = difftool -d --symlinks
```

But that requires:

- to create a `git mklink` command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core\git-mklink:

#!/bin/sh

cmd.exe /c "mklink \"$2\" \"$1\"" > /dev/null
```

- to patch msysgit 1.8.3:

```
cd /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Git/libexec/git-core/
$ patch < ~/git-difftool.patch
```

With `git-difftool.patch`:

```
    --- git-difftool    Sun Jun  2 11:28:06 2013
    +++ git-difftool    Tue Jul  9 00:42:02 2013
    @@ -283,7 +283,7 @@
                exit_cleanup($tmpdir, 1);
            }
            if ($symlinks) {
    -           symlink("$workdir/$file", "$rdir/$file") or
    +           !system("git", "mklink", "$workdir/$file", "$rdir/$file") or
                exit_cleanup($tmpdir, 1);
            } else {
                copy("$workdir/$file", "$rdir/$file") or
    @@ -448,7 +448,7 @@
        my $indices_loaded = 0;
    
        for my $file (@worktree) {
    -       next if $symlinks && -l "$b/$file";
    +       next if $symlinks;
            next if ! -f "$b/$file";
    
            if (!$indices_loaded) {
```

---

Before Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), "[`git difftool --dir-diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6a4f5dadd3d373db29053697aaefc67e31416699/Documentation/git-difftool.txt#L23)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool#Documentation/git-difftool.txt---dir-diff))</sup> mishandled symbolic links.

See [commit 5bafb35](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5bafb3576ac8eb8464ddd5cc14a1211aaa46364b) (22 Sep 2021) by [David Aguilar (`davvid`)](https://github.com/davvid).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6a4f5da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a4f5dadd3d373db29053697aaefc67e31416699), 03 Oct 2021)</sup>

> ### [`difftool`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5bafb3576ac8eb8464ddd5cc14a1211aaa46364b): fix symlink-file writing in dir-diff mode
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Alan Blotz</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Đoàn Trần Công Danh</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: David Aguilar</sup>

> The difftool dir-diff mode handles symlinks by replacing them with their readlink(2) values.
> This allows diff tools to see changes to symlinks as if they were regular text diffs with the old and new path values.
> This is analogous to what "[`git diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5bafb3576ac8eb8464ddd5cc14a1211aaa46364b/Documentation/git-diff.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> displays when symlinks change.
>
> The temporary diff directories that are created initially contain symlinks because they get checked-out using a temporary index that retains the original symlinks as checked-in to the repository.
>
> A bug was introduced when difftool was rewritten in C that made difftool write the readlink(2) contents into the pointed-to file rather than the symlink itself.
> The write was going through the symlink and writing to its target rather than writing to the symlink path itself.
>
> Replace symlinks with raw text files by unlinking the symlink path before writing the readlink(2) content into them.
>
> When [18ec800](https://github.com/git/git/commit/18ec800512eb0634a0bf5e86b36ed156fbee73f3) ("`difftool`: handle modified symlinks in dir-diff mode", 2017-03-15, Git v2.13.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0e758ac5a8073983774dee15f1cd3d3b6c4bb5fd) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/92f74a61921a774f2f3e7386fc927247a54a0d22)) added handling for modified symlinks this bug got recorded in the test suite.
> The tests included the pointed-to symlink target paths.
> These paths were being reported because difftool was erroneously writing to them, but they should have never been reported nor written.
>
> Correct the modified-symlinks test cases by removing the target files from the expected output.

And, still Git  2.34:

See [commit 28c10ec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/28c10ecbfcd68062da602de98702bab71d76b12b), [commit 8e2af8f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e2af8f0db329a8c0211a309fa9cb611b6dc2517), [commit 2255c80](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2255c80c91da9ed7fa127dad3aa92eb9f448c88b), [commit 4ac9f15](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ac9f15492b69ef3a0334ca66b1ef4be00c79b47) (30 Sep 2021) by [David Aguilar (`davvid`)](https://github.com/davvid).
See [commit 77bd616](https://github.com/git/git/commit/77bd616367905437fe6181611e0c65fe23160ea1) (23 Sep 2021), and [commit 93a8ed2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93a8ed28ea29fe1b5691e3e3d93a1870df717ac0) (20 Sep 2021) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0cc4ec1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0cc4ec15504c41d9b42709a4f343d3fed9480745), 11 Oct 2021)</sup>

> ### [`difftool`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2255c80c91da9ed7fa127dad3aa92eb9f448c88b): refactor dir-diff to write files using helper functions
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: David Aguilar</sup>

> Add a helpers function to **handle the unlinking** and writing of the dir-diff submodule and symlink stand-in files.
>
> Use the helpers to implement the guts of the hashmap loops.
> This eliminate duplicate code and safeguards the submodules hashmap loop against the symlink-chasing behavior that [5bafb35](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5bafb3576ac8eb8464ddd5cc14a1211aaa46364b) ("`difftool`: fix symlink-file writing in dir-diff mode", 2021-09-22, Git v2.34.0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a4f5dadd3d373db29053697aaefc67e31416699) listed in [batch #10](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0785eb769886ae81e346df10e88bc49ffc0ac64e)) addressed.
>
> The submodules loop should not strictly require the `unlink()` call that this is introducing to them, but it does not necessarily hurt them either beyond the cost of the extra `unlink()`.

```c
/* Write the file contents for the left and right sides of the difftool
 * dir-diff representation for submodules and symlinks. Symlinks and submodules
 * are written as regular text files so that external diff tools can diff them
 * as text files, resulting in behavior that is analogous to to what "git diff"
 * displays for symlink and submodule diffs.
 */
static void write_standin_files() {...}
```

Comment: There are two additional possibilities to create symlinks on Windows that don't require running always with Admin rights: 1. Disable UAC. 2. Use local SSH server with non-admin account and invoke 'ssh user@localhost mklink foo bar'.