# How to open git difftool for multiple files in a single Bcomp3 window?

Tags: git, beyondcompare, difftool

When using `git difftool --tool=bc3` from Git-Bash I got a BC3 window for *each* file. But to see the next window I had to close the previous one.

I wanted to see *all* diffed files at the *same time* as tabs in a single BC3 window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the right hint on StackOverflow: [#17736427](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736427/git-difftool-in-windows-to-see-list-of-all-changed-files-in-addition-to-file-dif).
Using `git difftool --dir-diff` (having BC3 configured as difftool) is OK for me.
Who wants to use this, may find the BC3 switch `/expandall` helpful.

My previous solution was, to call git-difftool *recursively*.
May be this trick is helpful for someone else. So I want to share it here.

Change your git-config like this:

`[difftool "bc3_all"]
    cmd = "git difftool --tool=bc3_single \"$REMOTE\" &"
[difftool "bc3_single"]
    cmd = "bcomp \"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\""`

My first attempt was to start BC3 directly as a background process:

`[difftool "bc3"]
    cmd = "bcomp \"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\" &"`

It did not work, because `$LOCAL` is usually a temparary file.
When the BC3 window(s) show up, the `$LOCAL` file is already deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Edit .gitconfig, add below line to `[alias]` section.

> dt = difftool --dir-diff --no-symlinks

run `git dt` to check all differences.

Reference: https://forum.scootersoftware.com/forum/beyond-compare-4-discussion/version-control-aa/84141-get-bc4-to-open-all-windows-instead-of-one-at-a-time-with-git-difftool