# 'git difftool --dir-diff commit-id' giving error

Tags: linux, git

I am using diffuse as a `diff` tool over Linux, but when I use the git command

```
$ git difftool --dir-diff
```

for opening the modified files in a directory, I get the following error :

```
Error processing argument "/tmp/git-difftool.nUMQD7/left/".  Directory not expected.
```

The same error is seen even if I use `$git difftool --dir-diff commit-id^!`. can anyone please let me know what is the issue here? If I use `$git difftool file1` where file1 is one of the modified files, it works perfectly fine and opens the graphical diff. But I would like to open the graphical diff for all the modified files. Please let me know how can I do that.

Comment: Is there any chance that in the new git commit, what used to be a file is now a directory ? Maybe something was called  "make" and was a file, and now "make" is a directory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diff tool that your git uses probably doesn't support recursive comparison.
What is in your .gitconfig , by the line diff ? (probably *diffuse*)

[Configure your diff tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897826/how-to-open-git-difftool-for-multiple-files-in-a-single-bcomp3-window) to be able to use a recursive directory comparison command.

[What are the best diff tools for Git?](https://www.slant.co/topics/1324/~diff-tools-for-git)  use Kdiff3 or Meld, they are great IMO.

[git's git-difftool documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool)

Comment: not sure though, may be issue was with diffuse. using meld now and its working fine.

Comment: The error message you had is one from diffuse (that is how I supposed this tool was used on your computer for git diff). Basically, git difftool passed arguments to diffuse, and diffuse expected those to be files paths; not folders paths.

Comment: is there a solution to this problem with diffuse as well ?

Comment: I am not too sure about this one. It should be, as even the official git difftool page specifies diffuse as a valid diff tool. Maybe ask to developer/maintainer of diffuse themselves (maybe they have a forum or irc).

Comment: diffuse does not look like it has dir-diff as meld does.  The last release appears to be 2014, and this feature was requested 2011 but with no action.   I LOVE diffuse, I hate the way meld scrolls, and separates its check summery indicators, but it looks like diffuse has become abandonware.   PLEASE tell me I am wrong!  :-(